# What's the most elegant way to eat a well-filled jelly doughnut (donut)?

Tags: food, snack-food

in which the jelly does not escape from where it's supposed to be?

Even when someone is holding it with the bite marks pointed straight up, that doesn't seem to stop jelly inside from overflowing the space that it had just seconds ago occupied without apparent issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you asking how you could eat a jelly-filled doughnut without creating a mess ?

Comment: Maybe you should avoid eating jelly donut in public or wherever you care more about eating elegantly.

Comment: @VarunKN That is the primary desired attribute of a good solution.

Comment: Don't take me wrong. I asked that just to understand the question better, so as to suggest an apt solution.

Comment: @VarunKN I'm not taking you wrong, just answering a friendly clarification question :-)

Comment: All right. No harm, no foul.

Answer (score 4):

you could put it on a plate and eat it with a knife and fork. Any filling would overflow on to the plate and you can mop it up with other bits of doughnut.

Comment: In addition, use a sharp serrated knife to saw through the doughnut. Only press down very gently, to avoid squeezage.

Comment: (+1) Biting into something and handling food with your hands is not very “elegant” to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly the first key is to find the "entrance wound" as described in another answer. Even then, taking small bites will still cause a jelly-lanche if you aren't careful.

The challenging jelly flow is caused by compressing both the top and the bottom of the jelly chamber while biting, resulting in a net flow of jelly out of the jelly chamber.

To avoid this, continue to hold the jelly donut with bite marks upward, but do not bite through both the top and bottom of the jelly chamber simultaneously, instead alternate tipping the donut toward and away, and biting half the filling and the top and bottom of the chamber (respectively) on subsequent bites.

Works for any high-viscosity filling. Also helpful on jucy lucy burgers, over-filled grilled cheese, densely packed burritos, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a small bite and suck a lot of the jelly out before you eat the rest.  It works, but I wouldn't exactly call it "elegant".

Answer (score 1):

Jelly is supposed to flow. If you do not want it to run off, you might want to cool down the doughnut to a state in which the jelly becomes a bit more rigid. Solid jelly cannot flow like its semi-solid form. The only other way of avoiding a mess is to use a tissue paper. There's not much you can do to avoid a "run-off jelly" situation, it is supposed to do that. But this doesn't qualify as a life hack.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect it until you find the entrance wound. If you start eating here it makes less mess than any other way. Also hold it with the hole and your bite marks at the top, so gravity is on your side as well.

Answer (score 0):

extend your pinky finger :) for maximum elegance.. also after first bite squice some jam on to newly exposed bread, bite that and repeat  so your not biting in to the middle so jam has a hollow to sit in..  quite hard to explane with words so may be type in to youtube im sure someones made a video.. keep practicing